# How can i open and process super heavy 800PB csv file?

Tags: csv, bigdata

How can i open a file that is 800 petabytes?

It's a file for some data science competition-  807167556410028 kb = 800000,556410028 TB = ~800PB

It's archived into 600 mb but i can't unzip it due to big size.
Is it possible to read the first 1000 rows from the zipped archive with pandas?

[image: petab]

Comment: Step back for a second.  Consider what kind of zip compression algorithm can turn 800PB into 582MB.  The dictionary is at the end of the zip file, so that's a fatal mishap.

Comment: @HansPassant, thx , i m using zipfile lib to open it and getting memory error

Comment: @HansPassant, dont understand this thing about dictionary at the end of file

Comment: There is probably a good reason why it's for a competition. Try to determine the used zip algorithm, read the RFC and write an algorithm specific to that problem. There won't be a ready-to-use solution for this problem (which is kind of the point of a competition - something like this is considered a "ZIP-Bomb" if you want to read up on it)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, what is RFC?

Comment: @ERJAN Usually the basis for most open standards. You can look them up online, for example on rfc-editor.org or tools.ietf.org (There are RFCs for HTTP, HTML, FTP, etc. I'm sure there is one for various compression algorithms)

Comment: Hint: A very compact way to stuff a lot data into a zip file is to define a huge repeating block, where every single bit of compressed data expands into the whole block. If for example your initial data chunk is half the size of your file, you would get a huge amount of data in total. e.g: 300 MB data times every bit in the remaining 300 MB =~ 100 PB

Comment: Oh, btw.: Is that competition still ongoing and do you intent to participate?

Comment: i m taking part yes

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer -  only 5 attempts to submit, 40 d left, deadline 9feb

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, i m using chunksize = 1mln. 2mln fails - mem error.. i should use some big data framework, like pyspark etc. but a hadoop cluster needs big ram or workstation right?

Comment: You are still approaching this the wrong way. Try to figure out how a zip file works and build something yourself that only reads the first 1.000 lines (or whatever your actual goal is). Since this is for an active competition I can't help you any further - that would be cheating ;)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, thx i will do. u want join?

Comment: No thanks, good luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205025/discussion-between-erjan-and-manfred-radlwimmer).

Comment: would be nice if you mentioned the URL of the competition, then I can download the zip file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import zipfile
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('bigfile.zip')
file = archive.open('big.csv')
textfilereader = pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=1000000)
df = textfilereader.get_chunk()

#df now is the dataframe.
```

This is somewhat partial answer as it just reads chunksize number of rows.

p.s. i tested it with 3mln rows, it fails with memory error.

p.p.s. Its the bug of my winrar archive program! I installed 7zip and it shows it's only 5GB! Lol, good lesson to learn, sometime it's the program, not the dataset!